# ArrayList getting changed without any operation on it

Tags: android, arraylist, android-edittext, adapter, addtextchangedlistener

I am trying to write a login in Android. The Logic is I am initiating an ArrayList in a constructor of a PopupWindow. In that PopupWindow I am showing a list using RecyclerView, by passing this ArrayList into the constructor of the Adapter Class. In that list I am using an EditText to search the list using `addTextChangedListener`.

The code is as follows,

**MainActivity.Java**

```
ArrayList<CompanyModel> companyList , backupCompanyList;
CompanyAdapter companyAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 //initialisation of both arraylists
    companyList = getCompanylist();
    backupCompanyList = companyList;

}

 // inner class declared in the MainActivity.java
public class ShowCompanyData{

    public ShowCompanyData(){

      //initialise popupwindow
      //get view of recyclerview and other view components of the popupwindow , and setadapter to the recyclerview

       companyAdapter = new CompanyAdapter(context , companyList );

       et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                        String text = et_search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                        companyAdapter.filter(text);

                }
            });
    }
 }

  //this button belongs to the Layout file of MainActivity.
  public void showPopupList(View v){
     // this is a button click where i am showing the company list popupwindow
       companyListPopupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
  }
```

**CompanyAdapter.java**

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CompanyAdapter.ViewHolder> {


Context context;
ArrayList<CompanyModel> mainArrayList;
ArrayList<CompanyModel> list;

 // other imp methods are also written , but not shown because not necessary to show here

    public CompanyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CompanyModel> mainArrayList) {

       this.context = context;
       this.mainArrayList = mainArrayList;
       this.list = new ArrayList<>();
       this.list.addAll(mainArrayList);

    }


    public void filter(String charText) {

        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mainArrayList.clear();

        if (charText.length() == 0) {

            mainArrayList.addAll(list);

        } else {

           for (CompanyModel wp : list) {

            if (wp.getCompanyName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {

                mainArrayList.add(wp);

            }

           }
        }   

    notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Here the issue I am facing is, when I search something in in the EditText of PopupWindow where the list of Company's is shown, the ArrayList backupCompanyList is getting modified same as the companyList ArrayList.

My question is, I am not assigning anything to the backupCompanyList, also not passing it as a parameter to the Adapter Class, still when I debug the app the backupCompanyList are showing same contents as companyList, after searching anything in the EditText.
Where the backupCompanyList should contains the data (unchanged) assigned in `OnCreate` and should not modify the changes, because there are no operations or assignments done to the backupCompanyList in the entire program.

Can anyone guide me to overcome this issue.

**Note** :

1. I have not written full code, I have written only necessary code
2. Both ArrayLists (companyList & backupCompanyList) are showing proper data before entering any text into EditText of search. And issue is occuring only after searching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your Activity's `onCreate` method, your are assigning `companyList` reference to `backupCompanyList` reference. Both `companyList` and `backupCompanyList` are referring to the same ArrayList object reference returned from `getCompanyList()` method. That's why, it's reflecting both lists are changing together. In actual, there's only one ArrayList object.

Instead of:

```
companyList = getCompanyList();
backupCompanyList = companyList;
```

Use

```
companyList = getCompanyList();
backupCompanyList = new ArrayList<>(companyList);
```